# How can I store entire contents of a Perl array to a scalar variable?

Tags: perl

How can I store entire contents of an array to a scalar variable.
eg:

```
my $code = do { local $/; <FILE HANDLE>; };
```

This works fine for file handles but I need this for an array.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Go up a level of abstraction, why are you trying to store an array in a scalar?  What is the purpose of this attempt?  With these questions answered, we may actually be able to give you useful help.

Comment: most important question: what exactly are you doing with the scalar variable afterward?

Answer (score 13):

Use [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html).

```
my $str = join '', @array;
```

Comment: This method also works swell if you want a quick way to separate the content of your string with line breaks for output, but note the double quotes. `my $str = join "\n", @array;`

Answer (score 5):

You can also take a reference to the array:

```
my @array = 'a'..'z';

my $scalar = \@array;

foo( $scalar );

sub foo {
    my $array_ref = shift;

    for my $f ( @$array_ref ) {

       do_something( $f ); 

    }
}
```

Which approach you take really depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

```
@arr = ("1","2","3") ;
my $arr = "@arr" ;
print "$arr";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use a scalar variable as a filehandle:

```
my $bigbuffer;
my $f;
open $f, ">", \$bigbuffer; # opens $f for writing into the variable $bigbuffer
# do whatever prints fwrites etc you want here
```